# Update a column to same value for all rows in a group of the group by

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-13

I have the following table:

| name | key | uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| na1 | k1 | NULL |
| na2 | k2 | NULL |
| na3 | k1 | NULL |

If two or more rows have the same **`key`** value then I want to update the `uuid` value to the same uuid for those rows. If the key is unique then that row should have a unique uuid value.

Following is the desired outcome:

| name | key | uuid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| na1 | k1 | 8274e89f-b119-4326-814d-4a864bbbe207 |
| na2 | k2 | 9a6c5f68-a3c2-4250-ac31-cc8c86a6440c |
| na3 | k1 | 8274e89f-b119-4326-814d-4a864bbbe207 |

Any ideas how to achieve this?

Comment: Please consider reading  [these suggestions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql/2977#2977).

Comment: *Following is the desired outcome* Where the values for `uuid` column are taken from?

Comment: @Akina: UUID values are to be generated

Comment: @mustaccio : thanks for the pointer and the edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this, may be

```
with u (key, uuid) as (
select distinct on (key) key, gen_random_uuid() as uuid from test
)
update test t1 set uuid = (select u.uuid 
  from u
  where u.key = t1.key)
```

Answer (score 1):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT DISTINCT key, GEN_RANDOM_UUID() uuid
              FROM test )
UPDATE test
SET uuid = cte.uuid
FROM cte
WHERE test.key = cte.key;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f4f16265f49eba3e8306e1348d39fde1

Comment: This also seems to work

Comment: It is functionally equivalent, but the plans will likely be different. This one sorts on the generated UUIDs, which is unnecessary. Since yours probably is a one-time use case that's likely immaterial.